# TK combo boxes & restricting their size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have a tkinter-based gui that has a sidepanel with comboboxes.  They are all contained within a frame for easy packing.

Thing is if I put a "long_test_level_for_instance" the width of the combobox grows to accommodate that(whether such a string is selected or not)

What I would like is a fixed width combobox/frame. Is this doable?  it was a pain todo it in GTK but I found a way, it is automatic in qt and I am wondering now for tk

--edit--

`self.framePLOTSEL.pack_propagate(False)`  in conjunction with `width=...` 
This however clips the content of the combobox when it is expanded (its expected to be clipped when collapsed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox widget has a `width` attribute which you can use to control the width of the combobox. However, the dropdown menu will always be the same width as the control, so you won't be able to see all of the characters in long items.

Comment: thanks, I am using the width attribute. With pyQT4 while the collapsed combo has a cutdown texted, the actual dropdown shows the full text length. Ill accept this answer mind as it does capture a limit of tk